# When you have to call in a professional for some home improvement steps, how can you verify a good job was done?

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring

*(I know this 'Home Improvement' SE instance leans heavily towards DIY, but in some DIY projects there are steps that are "above the homeowner's pay grade," and it becomes smart to hire that work out.  In that light, I hope this question is still considered relevant here.)*

When it came time to replace the tile flooring in my house, I knew I wanted vinyl plank (LVP), but I didn't exactly want to be the one breaking, chiseling, and grinding 2000 sqft of tile & mortar off my slab-on-grade foundation.  So even though I felt confident that I could DIY the plank installation, I decided to hire out the entire job.   I went with someone who had done flooring work for me in the past (engineered wood), and their results were essentially perfect.

But this time around, the results have been disappointing.  It seems clear to me that their current crew cut corners, and didn't level out the concrete foundation sufficiently.  It hasn't been very long since the install, and already in high traffic areas I have failing joints, where clearly there was a steep depression in the slab underneath the LVP.  (In many of these, you can clearly feel the planks spring down into a depression when your foot lands.)

I've had the installer back out to show them these spots, and they agreed that those areas need to be redone.  But there are other areas that I worry will fail in the future, and the installer seems to be downplaying that possibility.

I basically hear 3 different noises when I walk across my house now:

- (A) Cracking noises where the joints have already failed (confirmed by installer as needing repair under their warranty)
- (B) Clicking noises that I fear are also soon-to-be-failing joints (but could possibly just be relief of pressure/tension in joints that build up during the day due to localized thermal expansion/contraction.[*]
- (C) *I am a very heavy-footed walker, so this noise happens for me but not other family members so much, but:*  Thunking noises where the padding on the underside of the plank slaps against the concrete of the foundation as I walk over them.  (In my head, this could be either:  a wider & shallower depression that the planks span over like a bridge, or planks that have bowed up slightly during the hottest part of the day, due to localized thermal expansion).

So, here's my conundrum:  the installer tends to downplay (B) and (C), as though they aren't a concern:

- Insinuates that these locations aren't clear joint failures (possibly having the alternative explanations I listed above.)
- Says "the new floor needs time to relax" (it's been 3 months)
- When I point out that the manufacturer's warranty specifies no more that 3/16th inch variance in the subfloor over any diameter of 10 feet, the installer says that's an unreasonable criteria, especially when re-flooring a furnished house (empty other than large furniture).

*One the one hand:*  this is a person I've known a long time, and have previously trusted to do me right.

*On the other hand:* there is a clear incentive to downplay issues beyond what is obviously broken.

... and I am not an expert in LVP flooring systems and expected results, so I don't know what to think.  I don't want my manufacturer's warranty voided because of improper installation, and I don't want to end up salty over marginal joints that fail after the installer's labor warranty expires.

I feel like I need to call in an uninvolved expert to weigh in on the issues.  But I don't know where to find one.  The obvious thing might be:  call some other installer, and ask them to assess the original installer's results.  But that could also be a conflict of interest.  ***It almost feels like what I need is a "flooring inspector", but how do I find one?***

[*] I am reasonably certain that this installation crew left the recommended gap between my wall plates and the new flooring, to allow the floating floor to expand/contract properly.

Comment: You're the customer.... regardless of the installer's opinions, you've paid for work to be done up to your standards. Don't back down unless the installer can prove to you that you're wrong about it.

Answer (score 1):

LVP is very forgiving to floors that are not perfectly smooth.  So only the cracked joints are concerning to me.

One issue is the old tile was removed. LVP can be and is commonly installed over tile.  The extra height of only 8mm or less is usually insignificant. However it is now done and I suspect that there was quite a bit of "debris" left from the tile removal. ( grout high spots and divots from concrete being chipped. possibly tile "litter" that was not swept or vacuumed up)
This is making most of the noise when you walk.  Back to that later.

LVP has very little expansion/ contraction and does not need acclimatation time
as other flooring does. I believe that your fear of localized thermal expansion is unfounded here. The idea of the planks bowing is unlikely as well.

To address your issue of the crunching sounds I believe the entire floor needs to be removed. There are most likely  grout high spots and litter that need to be removed and divots that need to be filled in.
I would demand that the contractor pours leveling compound to further smooth the floor.

Finally the seams, when attached properly and the floor laying down, are very hard to separate. If the seams are coming apart they probably were not done properly.  When done correctly the seams should be all but invisible on all 4 sides.  If you can see the seams while standing normally, the floor was not installed properly.

I think there is a lot the contractor needs to do to correct your floor.

Edit: Regarding the "thumping" sound you hear when walking.
This requires some patience. A new LVP floor installed over a surface that is not perfectly flat and smooth, (most are not) will give some "pop" and "thump" when walking over areas that are not in direct constant contact with the subfloor.  In time,( A few days to weeks depending on the type of LVP) the LVP will "relax" and these sounds will go away.

Comment: "3/16th inch variance in the subfloor over any diameter of 10 feet, the installer says that's an unreasonable criteria" - yeah, if you're not going to re-float the floor, GFL. Hope they don't do large format tile. That's *one* sixteenth, *throughout*. Which I thought was unreasonable, until I did LFT on a fresh pour done by consummate professionals; one spot had a dip so it needed more back butter. Otherwise it was optically freaking flat. If a dude didn't come back an hour after the pour and float their ass off sweating balls having like 15m left to do it=garbage. Any less an hour is too soon

Comment: @RMDman I should clarify:  I said "cracking" to denote a sound, not "cracked" to denote visual breakage.  (Breakage is apparently below the finish layer.) No seams have visually separated anywhere.  I inspected the job over the 3 days, and in the areas where I saw bare foundation were very clean.  What I *did* see in one room were divots, and -- big surprise -- that's where most of the trouble areas are.  There are no crunching noises that would indicate loose debris.  Just cracking, clicking, and thunking as described.  All 3 noises seem it indicate low spots of one degree or another.

Comment: @RMDman based on your info about thermal stability, I now suspect that "cracking" noises are breaks in the thick parts of the tiles, and "clicking" may be breaks in the interlocking tabs (which aren't long enough to visually show a separation.)

Comment: @RMDman  "LVP is very forgiving to floors that are not perfectly smooth."   Should I infer from that that the "thunking" noises when stepping onto a larger shallow area is not concerning?

Comment: @GogTheGuilder, see the edit of my answer.

Comment: So "crackling" not "cracking."

Comment: RMDman thanks.  In my case it has been 3 months since install, so I was expecting it to be relaxed by now.     @Huesmann yes "crackling" is the proper the word I was needing.

Comment: So,  yes, the subfloor was not prepped properly and needs to be filled and leveled.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend contacting the flooring manufacturer, they will be able to judge the installation and if installed properly stand behind their product. If it is not installed correctly have them give you that in writing. Do not waste time, that will hurt you. Also confirm everything to the contractor in writing and if it were verbal write down what you stated and what his response was and send it as a confirmation to your conversation.  Then I suggest you contact a law professional to determine your next step. You hired them in good faith.

Comment: I think your advice is sound, but would be psychologically easier to apply if I didn't know the installer personally.